# Find and replace rows from one worksheet into another

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks, both layouts are the same.  The workbook which the VBA code in is my original and the second work book has some overlay information.  What I am trying to do is for every row on the second workbook is find it on the original and copy this rows information over it, if its not found then add that row in as a new row.  I am comparing the column G as this column the data will never change this is a unique ID.

I am getting a compile error (method or data member not found) on the .Find on line: -

```
Set rngFound = .Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=wbol.Worksheets("DLT Formatted").Range("G:G"), _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
```

This is the VBA code I have so far: -

```
Set wbol = Workbooks.Open("C:Documents\Overlay.xls")    
Set sht2 = Workbooks("Overlay").Worksheets("Overlay Template")
            With sht2
                For Each Row In Range("G:G")
                    Set rngFound = .Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=wbol.Worksheets("Overlay Template").Range("G:G"), _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
                    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                        rngFound.Select
                        Selection.Copy
                        Workbooks("Original Template").Worksheets("original").Range(rngFound).PasteSpecial
                    End If
                    Next
            End With
```

I have amended my code, now I am getting and Object required error on the same line.  I am new to VBA so not sure I understand why this is happening: -

```
With sht2
        For Each Row In Range("G:G")
            Set rngFound = wbol.Worksheets("Overlay Template").Range("G:G").Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                rngFound.Copy
                Workbooks("Original Template").Worksheets("original").Range(rngFound).PasteSpecial
            End If
        Next
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The "LookIn" parameter can only be one of the following XlFindLookIn constants: xlFormulas, xlValues, or xlNotes.

For the range to search, you would do

```
Set rngFound = wbol.Worksheets("Overlay Template").Range("G:G").Find(What:=.cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
```

The preceding . in ".cell.Value" is important. More information on the Find method can be found on the [Microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)

You can also do a straight rngFound.copy in your code, there's no need to select it first.

The end code should look like

```
    With sht2
        For Each r In .Range("G:G")
            Set rngFound = wbol.Worksheets("Overlay Template").Range("G:G").Find(What:=r.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                    rngFound.Copy
                    Workbooks("Original Template").Worksheets("original").Range(rngFound).PasteSpecial
            End If
        Next
    End With
```

Comment: I'm new to VBA so trying to muddle my way through by website etc.  I am not sure if I understand what you mean.  I have changed the .find row to this 'Set rngFound = RangeToSearch.Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)'  but I am getting an object required error.

Comment: Sorry, RangeToSearch is meant to literally be the range you're searching. In your case, it would be what you originally placed in "LookIn" :  wbol.Worksheets("Overlay Template").Range("G:G"). I will edit the answer for clarity

Comment: Still getting an object error.  I will update my question with the changed code.

Comment: I have amended my code to make a few corrections, I should have included the full piece in the first place - my apologies.

Comment: Still getting that same Object required Error on the same line: -  Set rngFound = Workbooks("OverLay_Template").Worksheets("Overlay Template").Range("G:G").Find(What:=r.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

Comment: Try adding "Dim rngFound as Range" at the top of your code

Comment: apologies for the late reply, I;ve not been able to try this till this morning.  I have added 'Dim rngFound As range at the top of my code but I still get this same error 'run-time error '424' object required' on line  Set rngFound = Workbooks("OverLay_Template").Worksheets("Overlay Template").Range("G:G").Find(What:=r.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

Comment: I just checked and the code in your last comment is slightly different to the code I provided in the 'answer'. The above you provided is looking within a worksheet 'overlay template' within a workbook also called 'overlay template' - may I assume that's not actually meant to be the case?